# Sqlite3 error 2 arguments given (7given) when finding data

Tags: python, sqlite

```
def addPersonRec(Firstname, Surname, DoB, Age, Notes, DateCreated):
    con=sqlite3.connect("silver.db")
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO silver VAULES (NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", Firstname, Surname, DoB, Age, Notes, DateCreated)
    con.commit()
    con.close()
```

so my issue is i have improted sqlite 3 and when i run it i get this error  line 14, in addPersonRec
cur.execute("INSERT INTO silver VAULES (NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",Firstname, Surname, DoB, Age, Notes, DateCreated)
TypeError: function takes at most 2 arguments (7 given) please any ideas help

Comment: Looking at python's [sqlite3 docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html) it appears that you `cur.execute()` is expecting 2 parameters. The following will probably work:

```python
cur.execute("INSERT INTO silver VAULES (NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", (Firstname, Surname, DoB, Age, Notes, DateCreated))
```

Answer (score 0):

`.execute`'s second argument should be a tuple.

Also note that you have a typo. `VAULES` should be `VALUES`.

```py
cur.execute("INSERT INTO silver VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",
            (Firstname, Surname, DoB, Age, Notes, DateCreated))
```

Comment: hi i ran into another error with that: line 16, in addPersonRec
    (Firstname, Surname, DoB, Age, Notes, DateCreated))
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: silver

Comment: heres my script def Data():
    con=sqlite3.connect("silver.db")
    cur = con.cursor()
    
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS silver (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Firstname text, Surname text, DoB text,  \
        Age text, Notes text, DateCreated text)")
    con.commit()
    con.close()